# Cannot connect my springboot docker with my cassandra docker

Tags: spring, docker, cassandra, containers

I have some issues to dockerize my Spring boot Cassandra application. 
When I use Idea to run my project it's work fine correctly but when I turn my application into a docker container I have this issues : 
"RetryingCassandraClusterFactoryBean : All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))"

```
my application.properties: 
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=keyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
server.port=8081    

my cassandra :
cassandradb:
    image: "cassandra:latest"
    container_name: "cassandradb"
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "7191:7191"
      - "7001:7001"
      - "9160:9160"
      - "7000:7000"
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER: "myCluster"
      CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH: "GossipingPropertyFileSnitch"
      CASSANDRA_DC: "data"
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: "auto"

  photos:
    image: "photos:latest"
    container_name: "photo"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    links:
      - "cassandradb"
```

Comment: Please share complete docker-compose.yml.

Comment: This issue you have faced is related to Docker. Have you tried `extra_hosts` Docker option? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Answer (score 0):

Error happens, becouse your spring can`t reach cassandradb. You should connect or via host ip, or use`cassandradb` host, anc configure docker-compose.yml links part

Answer (score 0):

I develop a simple example about the CRUD spring boot application by Cassandra.
You can check it in [github](https://github.com/omidmohebbise/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/cassandra). here are a few differences in the comparison of mine.